# Error al reasignar una constante en Kotlin "Val cannot be reassigned" Kotlin - ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy creando una clase llamada RetrofitClientKt, inicializo la variable retrofit en null, creo que hasta ahi no tengo ningun error. Pero el problema me surge cuando inicializo la condicional if. la constante "retrofit" me manda un error que me dice "Val cannot be reassigned" y por ende no puedo retornar el valor de la variable de retrofit. Soy nuevo en kotlin. si podria explicarme alguien ¿Porqué me sucede eso?... Gracias de antemano.

```js
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

class RetrofitClientKt{

    private val retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getClient(baseUrl:String): Retrofit{

        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder() //Aqui me muestra el error donde me dice que "retrofit no puede ser reasignado"
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()

        }

        return retrofit //Por ende la no puedo retornar el valor de la variable retrofit
    }

}
```

Comment: El problema es que cuando usas "val" se refiere a una constante, un valor que no cambiara nunca, entonces, despues de pasar el if, intentas reasignar el valor de "retrofit" con Retrofit.Builder(),  algo que no puedes hacer por que se supone que lo declaraste como una constante y siempre sera nulo, para poder resolver esto utiliza "var" en vez de "val" y pruebas.

Answer (score 1):

En Kotlin ademas de los tipos básicos de variable como String, Int, Boolean, etc. Existen las palabras clave "val", "var", "lateinit var", "Const val".

La primera "val" se refiere a que el valor que almacenes en esa variable al momento de **EJECUCIÓN** de la aplicación lo que contenga dentro no se podrá modificar osea que es inmutable ejemplo:

```
val fechaDeNacimiento = "01/01/1000"
```

Nuestra fecha de nacimiento es constante debido a eso es val

La segunda "var" se refiere a que el valor que este dentro de nuestra variable podrá mutar, osea cambiar, ejemplo:

```
var edad = 1000
```

Nuestra edad aumenta todos los años no siendo constante así que deberá var.

La tercera "lateinit var" esta reservando un espacio para un valor que sera entregado/seteado próximamente, ejemplo:

```
lateinit var puntajeMasAlto: Int

if(puntajeActual > puntajeAnterior)
    puntajeMasAlto = puntajeAcutal
else
    puntajeMasAlto = puntajeAnterior
```

Y por ultimo "la Const val" se refiere a que el valor que almacenemos en esta variable sera constante desde el momento de **COMPILACIÓN**, osea que en el momento que el Programador genere una APK la variable ya sera seteada, ejemplo:

```
const val contrasenaDeAdmin = 123
```

Si nosotros tenemos una contraseña de admin no queremos que para nada que pueda ser modificada y cualquiera generar una nueva.

Espero te ayude mi respuesta y suerte en tu aprendizaje